# Immediately change the value of a cell from EX: 755 to 7:55

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I'm trying to input a number in a cell and within the same cell change the value to a time-like format.

For example, if I input 600 I want to immediately change it to 6:00

I'm using the MID function so far it helps but if only targeted in another cell.

Comment: Is this in a given column or entire sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to add a ":"  you can use:

```
cells(row,col).value = left(cells(row,col).value,len(cells(row,col).value)-2) & ":" & right(cells(row,col).value,2)
```

A little long, but should fit the bill and corrects for 1 or 2 digits before the 2 digit minutes.

---

For future posts, please post the code you used, so people can copy/fix your code, extrapolate some more information, or possibly correct systematic errors which may inherently prevent met intentions.

Comment: ActiveCell.Value also works for this, if you're using a change event.

Answer (score 0):

use the `Worksheet_Change()` event handler

place this in the wanted sheet code pane:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo exitEvent

    Target.Value2 = Format(Target.value, "00:00")

exitEvent:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```